# ProgressBar in Android shows only after completing some operation

Tags: android, android-progressbar, android-thread

I tried to use **ProgressBar** in my **Activity** when I execute a short-time operation. And I realized that when I set **ProgressBar** visibility to true, It becomes visible only after the operation was executed.

```
progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
calculate();
```

Then I found the solution that I have to set **ProgressBar** visibility in another **Thread**. So my question is: why do I have to set it in another **Thread**?

For example, if I leave my **ProgressBar** with true visibility on creation (in **onCreate()**), it will progress and I can interact with **UI** in that moment. I concluded that they execute in one thread and It's okay. But It seems to me I'm wrong.

Comment: try to do your operation in another thread not on ui thread ..  may be it takes a long time that freeze your ui

Comment: But anyway, if It takes a long time, I set visibility of ProgressBar to true before the execution of this operation

Comment: could you put some code to check with u

Answer (score 1):

The Android UI toolkit is not thread-safe. This means that you must not manipulate your UI from a worker/background thread. you must do all manipulation to your user interface from the UI (Main) thread.

Android UI toolkit include elements in `android.widget` & `android.view` packages

**Rule of Thumb:**

1. Do not block the UI thread (don't run operations that have unspecified time in UI thread)
2. Do not access the Android UI toolkit from outside the UI thread

This is explained in more details in [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads)

Running background threads using [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask) or [Loaders](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders) always allow you to update your UI upon the background thread results in their `onPostExecute()` and `onLoadFinished()` respectively.

So, as of your question, you have to update your `ProgressBar` from the UI thread not from other threads.

Comment: But in my code I’m updating Progress Bar from UI thread. The problem is that it’s updating after the operation, even if in code I firstly updating progress bar and then doing some operation

Comment: maybe this operation takes some time which makes main UI unblocked until it's finished; so it might need to be in background thread. Does the PorgressBar value depends on the result on a partial result of this operation?

Comment: Oh, maybe. No, it doesn’t depend